# How to change variable value using PUT method?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to change  the value of a variable when a button is clicked. For that I made a function that updates the database using ajax. Here is what I have so far:

```
 function atualizaBD(novoEstado) {
    $.ajax
        ({
            url:`/api/IgnicoesAPI/${id}`,
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Id : id,
                Estado: novoEstado
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);

            },

            error: function () {
                alert("ocorreu um erro!")
            }
        });
}
```

I have a variable called Estado and I want to change the value of that variable to a new one, novoEstado. 
Here is my controller:

```
     [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutIgnicoes([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Ignicoes ignicao, string novoEstado)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        if (id != ignicao.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }


          var ig = _context.Ignicoes.FirstOrDefault (ignicaoId => ignicaoId.Id.Equals(id));
        ig.Estado = novoEstado;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!IgnicoesExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

Right now, everytime the function an error occurs alerting "ocorreu um erro"

Here is my Model:

```
  public class Ignicoes
{

    public Ignicoes()
    {
        ListaOcorrencias = new HashSet<Ocorrencias>();

    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }

    public string Longitude { get; set; }

    //estado(recusada, aceite, em avaliacao, concluido)
    public string Estado { get; set; }


    public DateTime DataInicioPropostaIgnicao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataDecisaoIgnicao { get; set; }




    //lista de ocorrencias 
    public virtual ICollection<Ocorrencias> ListaOcorrencias { get; set; }

}
```

}

Comment: You should work on getting more details about the error; knowing that an error occurred does not help. Knowing what the error _is_ does. Do you have details returned in the failed request that give an error message?

Comment: It gives me an error 400 : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()  - referencing :44324/api/IgnicoesAPI:1

Comment: Is it your `return BadRequest()` that you're hitting, then? Looks like the code is expecting the body being `PUT` to have an `Id` property that matches the URL parameter. Do you have a sample of the body you're putting and the URL so we can confirm whether this is behaving as expected or not? I don't see your body including that `Id` property in your posted code, so seems to be working as designed.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question, but this is what I'm sending `{
    "id": 8021,
    "latitude": "38.513622",
    "longitude": " -7.569803",
    "estado": "concluido",
    "dataInicioPropostaIgnicao": "2020-02-15T00:20:00",
    "dataDecisaoIgnicao": "2020-02-14T00:20:00",
    "listaOcorrencias": []
}` I'm trying to change the Estado="concluido"  to "aceite", for example

Comment: You should update your JavaScript as posted, since that doesn't match the code there. Your posted JS only has you passing an `Estado` property (which you're converting to a number with the `+` operator) and no ID.

Comment: I've edited the javascript. I think that's what you meant.

Comment: Could you add the definition of `Ignicoes` as well? If you're hitting your code's other 400 error, it might be because the body can't be deserialized into an instance of that class.

Comment: Is it that `[Required]` on `Longitude` that's causing the 400, perhaps? I'm still not clear if your JavaScript code is complete since you added a comment that does include longitude but your JS doesn't have that. Also, why do you have a `novoEstado` parameter? Wouldn't you just want to get the new state from `ignicao` since that's the body of your post request?

Comment: The only parameter that I need to change is Estado the rest stays the same. I use novoEstado (newState) to simbolize the Estado that will be updated on my database. The [Required] isn't what's causing the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208083/discussion-between-teresa-alves-and-jacob).